# Make a matrix and make the selection

Tags: vbscript

This is for a string

I do not understand how to make the matrix and call itn VBScript, there is no Exit While so you cannot break the While loop unless you use the syntax Do While … Loop and Exit Do. Also, the VBScript (at least the Microsoft WSH) does not employ any boolean circuit optimisation, so if you write While j > 0 and arr (j – 1) > x this will cause the error of trying to access arr (-1) which is out of the valid subranges.

```
Option Explicit

Const N = 10

Dim Nums()
ReDim Nums(N)

Randomize
Dim i
For i = 0 To N
    ' Randomize the Numbers as Integers
    Nums(i) = Int(Rnd() * (N * 2))
Next

' Print out the Number Array
Sub PrintNum(Msg, arr)
    Dim i, s
    s = Msg
    For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
        s = s & " " & arr(i)
    Next
   Print s
End Sub

Sub InsertionSort(ByRef arr)
    Dim j, i, N, x
    ' Upper Bound of Array
    N = UBound(arr)
    For i = 1 To N
        j = i
        x = arr(i)
        Do While j > 0
            If arr(j - 1) > x Then
                ' Shift Big Numbers to The Right
                arr(j) = arr(j - 1) 
                j = j - 1   
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop 
        arr(j) = x
    Next
End Sub

PrintNum "Before: ", Nums
Call InsertionSort(Nums)
PrintNum "After: ", Nums
```

Comment: Halp to do a matrix pleeez

Answer (score 0):

[Split()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0764e5w5(v=vs.84).aspx) is an easy way to get an array of strings/letters from a single input string. As in:

```
Option Explicit

' Sort one dimensional array in place
Sub InsertionSort(ByRef arr)
    Dim j, i, N, x
    ' Upper Bound of Array
    N = UBound(arr)
    For i = 1 To N
        j = i
        x = arr(i)
        Do While j > 0
            If arr(j - 1) > x Then
                ' Shift Big Numbers to The Right
                arr(j) = arr(j - 1) 
                j = j - 1   
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop 
        arr(j) = x
    Next
End Sub

Dim aaTests : aaTests = Array( _
    Array("a few integers", Array(3, 2, 5, 1, 4)) _
  , Array("a few letters", Split("b d c a d a")) _
  , Array("a few words", Split("some words in arbitrary order")) _
  , Array("numbers", Empty) _
  , Array("strings", Empty) _
)

' Use fixed array, if you know the size at 'compile' time
Dim a(9), i 
For i = 0 To UBound(a)
    a(i) = CLng(1 + Fix(Rnd() * 20))
Next
aaTests(3)(1) = a 
aaTests(4)(1) = Split(Join(aaTests(3)(1)))

Dim aTest 
For Each aTest In aaTests
    WScript.Echo "--------", aTest(0), TypeName(aTest(1)(0))
    WScript.Echo "Before |" & Join(aTest(1), "|") & "|"
    InsertionSort aTest(1)
    WScript.Echo "After  |" & Join(aTest(1), "|") & "|"
Next
```

output:

```
cscript 48867059.vbs
-------- a few integers Integer
Before |3|2|5|1|4|
After  |1|2|3|4|5|
-------- a few letters String
Before |b|d|c|a|d|a|
After  |a|a|b|c|d|d|
-------- a few words String
Before |some|words|in|arbitrary|order|
After  |arbitrary|in|order|some|words|
-------- numbers Long
Before |15|11|12|6|7|16|1|16|17|15|
After  |1|6|7|11|12|15|15|16|16|17|
-------- strings String
Before |15|11|12|6|7|16|1|16|17|15|
After  |1|11|12|15|15|16|16|17|6|7|
```

Mark the difference between numbers and strings of digits; avoid useless cargo cult code like 'Dim a()' (fixed array of no size) or 'Call SomeSub(params)' (adding noise to be allowed to add noisy ()).